# MySQL 8 Recursive CTE query result returns error 1054

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

First of all, sorry for bothering with such simple question. But I can't find a mistake in my query.

I would like to add n count, but I keep getting -
*Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'lvl' in 'field list'*

What is my mistake here?

Query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE taxonomic_traverse (tsn, unit_name1, lvl) AS
(
    SELECT tsn, unit_name1, 1 lvl
        FROM taxonomic_units
        WHERE parent_tsn IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.tsn, t.unit_name1, lvl + 1
        FROM taxonomic_units tu
        JOIN taxonomic_units t ON tu.tsn = t.parent_tsn
)
SELECT * FROM taxonomic_traverse;
```

Comment: I assume `lvl` is not a column in the table `taxonomic_units`. Also your second part of the UNION should join to `taxonomic_traverse`, shouldn't it? You must join to the CTE name, not another reference to the base table.

Comment: Yes, `lvl` is not in the column list. I'll try to edit the query according to your suggestion about `join`

Comment: Sorry, It took a while for me to update on my results. I've read further into CTE's and I just wanted to thank you for your answer. It cleared some of the confusions about recursions.

Comment: Glad to help! Have fun with CTE's. They're complex and interesting.